# Javascript - Script doesn't work on second click

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addeventlistener

A basic question by a newbie…

I always encounter the same problem :
I often want an element "A" to show an element "B" on click when "B" is hidden, but to hide it when it is visible. Here are two different try that doesn't work :

```js
    let ref = document.getElementsByTagName('sup');
    let refContent = document.getElementsByTagName('i');
    
    for(let i = 0; i < ref.length ; i++) {
        ref[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (refContent[i].style.display == "inline") {
                refContent[i].style.display = "none";
            } else {
                refContent[i].style.display = "none";
            };
        });
    }
```

```js
let ref = document.getElementsByTagName('sup');
let refContent = document.getElementsByTagName('i');

for(let i = 0; i < ref.length ; i++) {
    if (refContent[i].style.display == "") {
        ref[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            refContent[i].style.display = "inline";
        });   
    } else {
        ref[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            refContent[i].style.display = "none";
        });   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post your HTML code here.

Comment: The first one is more likely to work, but fails because of what looks like a typo - it sets `refContent[i].style.display = "none";` in both cases - in other words, even if the style is already "none", it sets it to "none" once again. So the code will run, but nothing will appear to change. So `} else {
                refContent[i].style.display = "none";
            }` needs to be `} else {
                refContent[i].style.display = "inline";
            }` I think. Due to the lack of HTML I can't prove that this is the only problem, but it looks likely to be the main one.

Comment: The second attempt doesn't make any sense at all, as far as I can see, so I would forget about that one.

Comment: Oh actually another change you can make which would be better - inside the event handler the clicked event will be represented by `this`. So instead of `refContent[i].style.display` it's more robust and direct to write `this.style.display`

Comment: Thx a lot @Adyson ! Indeed, the problem came from my idiot mistake of writing two times the same instruction.

Case closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hi

I'm gonna change some variable names to make this easier to talk about. So, you start off strong

```
    // get all elements with tag sup
    let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('sup'); 
    //get all elements with tag i
    let showables = document.getElementsByTagName('i');
```

For each element `buttons` we want to *bind an onclick event listener*.  `showables` should respond to those clicks. You write

```
    //for every `button` bind this `event listener`
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (showable[i].style.display == "inline") {
            showable[i].style.display = "none";
        } else {
            showable[i].style.display = "none";
        };
    });
}
```

To make this a little more clear lets take out the `function` and give it a name

```
let show_hide = function(i) {
        if (showable[i].style.display == "inline") {
            showable[i].style.display = "none";
        } else {
            showable[i].style.display = "none";
        };
});

//for each button, bind show_hide
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', show_hide(i))
}
```

The loop there does exactly what you'd expect; it binds `show_hide` to each `button`.
What does `show_hide` do?

```
    //if the element is shown, hide it
    if (showable[i].style.display == "inline") {
        showable[i].style.display = "none";
    //if the element is not shown, hide it
    } else {
        showable[i].style.display = "none";
    };
```

as you can see that no matter what, `show_hide` hides the element!
so a quick change will fix this for you.

```
    if (showable[i].style.display == "inline") {
        showable[i].style.display = "none";
    //if not shown, show
    else {
****    showable[i].style.display = "inline";
    };
```

putting it all together, this should work

```
let show_hide = function(i) {
    if (showable[i].style.display == "inline") {
        showable[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
        showable[i].style.display = "inline";
    };
});

//for each button, bind show_hide
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', show_hide(i))
}
```

If you want my solution to this problem I'd be more than willing to solve this problem in my own way. Comment and let me know! I hope this helps

## fin

Answer (score -1):

I will interpret what you have written but I do not have the complete code I will fix some issues and update if/when you update your code by adding the markup (html).

You should put your selected elements in an array because some browsers will not let you loop over a NodeLists. You can change a NodeLists into an array in a few ways I like the `Array.From()` way. After changing the NodeLists into an array you can safely loop over the elements in the array using a `forEach()` loop.

```js
let ref = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('sup'));
let refContent = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('i'));
ref.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.target.getElementsByTagName('i').style.display = '' // do something
    });
});
```

This snippet will most likely not work as-is, I'm missing information to finish this script, but perhaps this is a good starting point for further exploration. (Search for stuff and add 'mdn', to get good results).

In stead of directly changing the style of an element it is better to either add or remove a css class which contains the css properties you desire. You can also [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Examples) a class: `element.toggle('className)`.

Comment: Thx a lot ! I tried this but I get an error : e.target.getElementsByTagName(...).style is undefined